# Android sqlite insert order is getting wrong

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my code for table creation

```
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RNOTIFICATIONS(Position VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,message VARCHAR, title VARCHAR, iconof VARCHAR);");
```

and insert data function is

```
public void insert_new_item(String n_message, String n_title,String n_icon) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String rows= String.valueOf((int)DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database, "RNOTIFICATIONS"));
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Position",rows+1);
    values.put("message", n_message);
    values.put("title", n_title);
    values.put("iconof",n_icon);
    database.insert("RNOTIFICATIONS", null, values);
    database.close();
}
```

INPUT: `insert_new_item(hi,Instagram, 2)`

OUTPUT: `[{message=1, iconof=Instagram, title=hi}]`

EXPECTED OUTPUT: `[{Position=1,message=hi,title=Instagram, iconof=2}]`

Insert command is inserting values in wrong columns. can anyone help. please
i have tried removing PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL But still it does the error.

Comment: Can you post the select query to get the data?

Comment: @Raghavendra yeah sure . hold on

Comment: @Raghavendra i found an error in that function & it solved the error . Thank you so much buddy :).  you saved my day.  I have been working on this error for hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with wrong cursor position. It was (0)

```
 map.put("message", cursor.getString(0));
```

It should have been (1)

`map.put("message", cursor.getString(1));`

Comment: There is no map in the question …

Comment: these lines were in the query function which i went to look after Raghavendra asked me for its snap & there i found the above error. I mean the insertion was perfect but my output code was wrong.